# Why my rails application fails to run in production if config.assets.compile = false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to rails so sorry if this is a stupid question. I built a Rails 3.2 app and was preparing to deploy in production.

I ran rake assets:precompile, it took a while and created some files in public/assets/ directory.

The problem is that when i started server in production it was giving the "We're sorry" error and i could not see a single new line in production log, although it had the proper permissions.

At nginx/webrick log, the only thing that showed up was:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

So i tried a few things and finally after setting config.assets.compile to true, it worked.

My question is why this happened? Is it a problematic file or something that precompile task were not able to compile?

There is a specific css file (only for IE) that i included this way:

```
<!--[if IE ] --><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie' %><!-- [endif]-->
```

Which is giving a 404 error. All other files were included using assets/stylesheets/application.css.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your file is named `ie` (and not `application`). By default Rails only compiles `application.js` and `application.css`.

By setting `config.assets.compile` to `true` you enabled the asset pipeline *fallback* which prepared your `ie.css` file.

To include your `ie.css` stylesheet into the compilation process you have to add it like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(ie.css)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did what you asked but i still have problems to run the app with precompile=false. Does Rails provide any information about which file is failing?

Comment: Normally `rake assets:precompile` stops of any error occurs, so I'd bet this (still) is a configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

In production, Rails expects you to precompile your assets rather than serve them dynamically.

You need to run `rake assets:precompile` and Rails will build the static assets needed to support your app in production. This typically involves turning your SASS and CoffeeScript into minified/compressed CSS and JavaScript respectively. This prevents the cost of compiling your script/stylesheets on every request, something you don't want happening in a production environment.

If you're missing a single stylesheet, like `ie.css` which you aren't serving via the asset pipeline, you can specify an absolute path to it to prevent the assets helpers from serving it out of `/assets`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/ie' %>
```